# Get unknown number of options into wordpress widget admin page

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

I have made a wordpress plugin that can fetch an unknown number of Google calendar feeds and show the next event for every calendar in a widget. It works, but right now I have hardcoded the feeds into the code. It does'nt seems like very good practise so I am planning for an admin interface. For every feed I add there is three pieces of information that are stored with them in an array: a) the feed url. b) A nickname for the feed. c) If the nickname should be shown.

Here is some ugly mockup of the admin interface I did just to show the idea:
[image: Screenshot of mockup]

My problems with this:

1. I know by all tutorials how to store one piece of information in one variable. But how do I store an unknown number of them? Could I use an array with the $instance variable? I have really no clue from the code samples I've seen of how to do that.
2. How do I make this dynamic, so for every feed I add it instantly shows up in the interface? There would be great to be able to change the order of them also.

I want to learn and regarding question number two I think I could come upp with something in javascript when I'm there. But for question number one I have no idea where to start looking. So if someone could give some hints and a push in the right direction I would be very thankful.

## Update

Thanks for the input. I really need to free some time to try to implement this, but i may take a few days more. The answer that was the most helpfull to me get the bounty...

Comment: usabillity tip: change the radio button labels, true and false isn't very user friendly.

Comment: I think your statement is true :-p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save array's with [add_option()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_option), [update_option()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_option) And read [get_option()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option)
I would recommend against this if you plan to store more then ~20.

```
<?php
$feeds = array(
    0 => array(
        'feedUrl' => 'http://calander.google.com/calname1',
        'nickname' => 'first calander',
        'useNick' => false
    ),
    1 => array(
        'feedUrl' => 'http://calander.google.com/calname2',
        'nickname' => 'birtday calander',
        'useNick' => true
    ),
    2 => array(
        'feedUrl' => 'http://calander.google.com/calname3',
        'nickname' => 'take out garbage days calander',
        'useNick' => false
    ),
);
add_option('calender_feeds', $feeds, '', 'no');
?>


<?php
//read feeds
$feeds = get_option('calender_feeds');
?>
```

As suggested for the dynamic adding of multiple field I suggest jQuery.

Comment: Thanks. Also lost on how to get the FORM to store to that array... :-/

Comment: Thanks is voting my answer up ;), What do you mean with the FORM to store?

Comment: I think the big problem is that I don't have enough understanding of PHP/HTML yet. But according to the examples on the Wordpress Widget API site, it is trivial to create a form that store one option in the database. But in this case I can't just do that. I would need to get the option first if it exist (which you showed how to). Then append data to the array, and lastly overwrite the old array with the new one. I can't just do that with a simple in html input-line. Sorry if I suck on explaining... But I will try doing some more research...

Comment: I thought this was you problem, I just wanted to check it. I suggest a tutorial of working with php and forms first. The widget API is great but probably to hard to start with.

Comment: Yeah! probably all three of you answered my vague question. I only asked for hints and I got them so... Back to the books :-)

Answer (score 1):

Why not just create a new table for this plugin wp_feedwhatever or similar then create a record for each feed.

The other way (which WordPress tends to use a lot) is serialized data - which is also a pain in the butt to work with.

The dynamic part can be done with jQuery.

Comment: The serialized data which wordpress uses in it's wp_options table is easy to use when used with 'add_option', 'update_option', 'get_option'

Answer (score 1):

This [Widgets API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API) may help. This is the codex for creating a widget.  I think this might be the best way to handle what you are try to achieve.  If you look at the bottom there is an example of a widget.  With this you can create multiple instances of the calander widget and each instance will have the three options you want.

The WP_Widget::form() is where you collect the user info for the three fields.

The WP_Widget::update() is for storing the info in the database.  Wordpress does a good job of doing the complex stuff for you.

The WP_Widget::widget() is for getting the data and using it in your widget.